# C++ vector pointer: point constant vector to a variable pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have two constant vectors:

```
const vector<int> A = { 0, 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89 };
const vector<int> B = { 13, 24, 35, 46, 57, 68, 79 };
```

and I want to switch between them like this

```
int main()
{
  vector<int> myVector;

  if ( something happens )
    point myVector to A;
  else
    point myVector to B;

  while ( a condition )
  {
    do something with ( myVector );
  }
}
```

How can I point to vector `A` or `B` and how should I declare `myVector`?

Comment: _"How can I point to vector A or B"_ Use a pointer perhaps?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pointing out your particular problems. Your pseudo code doesn't seem to be very helpful, to solve these.

Comment: This is by far the most stupid comment I have ever read on StackOverflow...

Comment: _"This is by far the most stupid comment"_ Which one do you mean actually??

Comment: The one where you said "Use a pointer perhaps?" I know that I can use pointers, I just don't know how to do it with vectors.

Comment: _"I just don't know how to do it with vectors. "_ Use a pointer to a (const) vector simple as that, shown it in my answer. Why so aggressive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a reference for that:

```
auto& myVector = somethingHappens ? A : B;
while ( a condition ) {
    do something with ( myVector );
}
```

Now `myVector` is a "new name" for either `A` or `B`, depending on your condition.

Answer (score 3):

As the simplest solution, you can use a copy:

```
int main() {
  vector<int> myVector;

  if ( /* something happens */ )
    myVector = A;
  else
    myVector = B;

  // ...
}
```

Since you cannot change the values in `A` or `B` anyway, that shouldn't make much difference.

If you're afraid about the copying overhead, you can also use a pointer:

```
int main() {
  const vector<int>* myVector = nullptr;

  if ( /* something happens */ )
    myVector = &A;
  else
    myVector = &B;

  // ...
}
```

But depending on what *`something_happens`* and *`do_something_with(myVector);`* actually are, there may be other solutions, appearing more elegant, or can be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative:

```
bool condition = /* evaluate something happens */;

while (a_condition)
{
    do_something_with(condition ? A : B);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the condition is compact you can declarae a reference and initialize it using the condition in the conditional operator. As for example

```
std::vector<int> &v = ( A < B ? B : A );
```

Otherwise you can use `std::reference_wrapper`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const std::vector<int> A = { 0, 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89 };
    const std::vector<int> B = { 13, 24, 35, 46, 57, 68, 79 };

    auto v = std::cref( std::max( A, B ) );

    for ( int x : v.get() ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
13 24 35 46 57 68 79
```

Or you can at first initialize the reference_wrapper by one vector and then reassign it. For example

```
auto p = std::cref( A );
if ( condition ) p = B;
```

Also take into account that you can use a lambda expression as condition in the conditional operator when you initialize a reference. So the condition can be compound.

```
std::vector<int> &v = ( [] { /* compound lambda */ }() ? B : A );
```